# How to flatten #include paths in multiple file

Tags: c++, shell, replace, sed, find

I'm working on a C++ project with multiple libraries in subfolders. The cloud IDE I'm using requires all files to be in the same folder to use cloud flashing features.
I now have 2 scripts. One that flattens the directory structure and one that flattens the includes to match the new layout.
So far I've been adding the following to the script I use to replace absolute path of the includes:

`find $(_CLOUD_SRC_FOLDER) -type f \( -iname \*.cpp -o -iname \*.hpp \) -maxdepth 3 -exec sed -i.bak 's/\#include "..\/lib\//#include "/g' {}`

The above line only works for `#include "../lib/filename.hpp"`. How can I reformat this to match `#include "any/path/filename.hpp"` and replace with #include "filename.hpp"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
find $(_CLOUD_SRC_FOLDER) -type f \( -iname \*.cpp -o -iname \*.h  -o -iname \*.hpp \) -maxdepth 3 -exec sed -i.bak 's/\(#include "\)[^"]*\/\([^"]*"\)/\1\2/' {} +
```

`#include` string and filename are captured from path and output using backreference.